# Expect scripts and ssh

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I've implemented expect script to automate ssh connection on some servers.

Issue appears when ssh tried to open connection with server for the 1st time, I got a yes/no question.

I had to perform connection manually 1st, then it won't appear again and script work good.

1st : I need your help to find step within the expect script to skip this question, is that possible ?

Comment: -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no just adding this to ssh will solve the issue, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is a example:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env expect

   spawn ssh root@127.0.0.1

   while {1} {
       expect "(yes/no)?" {
          send "yes\r"
       } "password: " {
           send "xxxxxxxx\r"
           interact 
           exit 0
       }
   }
   ```
2. While if your root purpose is just the automatic ssh, please have a try of sshpass, but sshpass usually is not default installation:

   ```
   `sshpass -p xxxxxxxx ssh root@127.0.0.1`
   ```
3. Here also provide a procedure for setup the public/private key pair, this make you access your destination server without password:

   ```
   Generate a key pair, id_dsa.pub id_dsa with following command:
       ssh-keygen -t dsa -b 1024 
   Move id_dsa to client:/home/xxxx/.ssh/ 
   Move id_dsa.pub to server:/home/xxxx/.ssh/, and "cat id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys"
   chmod 600 /home/xxxx/.ssh/* (both the id_dsa and remote authorized_keys)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
set timeout 30
spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "$usr@$ip"
expect {
    "RSA key fingerprint" {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
    -re "<regex for whatever the yes/no question is>" {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
    "assword:" {send "$password\r"}
}
sleep 5
interact
```

The will keep everything in a loop until the timeout time (30s). Then it will just move to the next line in your script. I also added an expect for RSA in case if you need it.